# Swipe left to refresh horizontall recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to implement this feature to my app.

The problem is, all swipeRefreshLayouts are only for pull down gesture.

I want to swipe left / right in my recyclerView, and when I've reached maximum left, then swipe layout and show refresh like in swipeRefreshLayout.

Is it possible?

Comment: So did you check the source code for the pull down gesture layouts? Seems like a good place to get some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomSwipeToRefresh extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private int mTouchSlop;
    private float mPrevX;

    public CustomSwipeToRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPrevX = MotionEvent.obtain(event).getX();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float eventX = event.getX();
                float xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - mPrevX);

                if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                    return false;
                }
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

use this **CustomSwipeToRefresh** instead of **SwipeRefreshLayout**

Comment: Thank's for answer! I have already used this code, but it doesn't work, or maybe I'm doing somethink wrong. I can't show Loader on left side, always showing on top.